# Render html into View MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Hi i am making my project in MVC, i which i want to add the control from the drop-down selection on right side div, (the black rectangle part in the image).

Now i have two requirements

1. Get the inner html or .html() of the right side div, and save this in the database along with the left side form values
2. I have another view details where i want to display the values of left side fields and render the inner html on right side, (i have the container div in my details view )..

[image: Create page image]

i am getting the html with following button click function

```
$('#SaveCone').click(function () {
        var a = $('#NewData').html();
        console.log(a);

    });
```

tell me please if you want another details, thanks for your kind help

Comment: This is just a matter of posting the HTML to the server, connecting to a database, and inserting a row somewhere, right? What are you stuck on specifically?

Comment: Yes correct, i just want to know how can i post the .html() data with form serialization ,no issues to get the data. THIS is my first requirement , second is to render  the data in another view

Comment: Posting raw html will give various security warnings on an MVC website, but it is possible. You will need to deactivate the security features mentioned in the error messages you will get.

Comment: I can have one column that can save my .html() data, and simply inject in  my view where i want to  display these html opbjects

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie that is another thing, i just want to know how can i post the data now from form to my database

Comment: Errrm... `$.post()` :)

Comment: You can combine any number of name + value properties, including your HTML, into a Javascript object and send that via an Ajax call. It will be received as it it were a form post. You need to show your client-side code and your controller method to receive the post.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: You can decorate a model property with [`[AllowHtml]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx) to help bypass the security warnings.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie actualy right side controls are from the mvc model

Comment: @Userdied if you place your right side div in partial view you can reuse it on any view just by calling @Html.Partial("PartialViewName")

Comment: Yes make sense, can i save the state of the right side, because at the time of page load the right side div is empty i am adding input type with dropdown.change function

Comment: e.g if i save the this  right side div with three input controls, when i reopen this view from the name of record there are three controls in that right side div @aleha

Comment: i am able to save the inner html in my table, u can help me to how can i inject this back to my another view @aleha thnx for coolaborate

Comment: @Userdied sorry, a can't understand you. ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is nice question

If you want to store your html into the database, simply use ajax ,

```
$('#urbutton).click(function () {
        var a = $('#yourForm).html();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/UrController/Uraction',
            data:
              $('#MyForm').serialize() + "&par2=" + a,
            success: function (data) {
                // ` alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

your controller looks like this

```
    public ActionResult Create(Table table, string par2)
            {
using (urcontext cntxt = new urcontext ())
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    table.data = par2;
                    cntxt.SaveChanges();
}... so on
```

this will store your data into database

**How to render the Html from database to the view**

simply use

```
<div id="container">

@HTML.Raw(model.data)

< /div>
```

Hope this will help you man